# GEE correlation structure's number of parameters

Tags: regression, variance, generalized-estimating-equations, identifiability

I am kind of confused on GEE correlation structure's number of parameters. Say I have 10 students(or clusters) and I measure their physical strength 10 times for each of them with their corresponding covariates over time. I want to specify GEE's unstructured correlation.

So for each person, I have 9 choose 2 parameters for correlation. That is 36 for each cluster(person). In total, I would have 360 different correlation parameters and I have an non identifiable model.

Is this correct?

Update:

Assume that 1 person got 9 measurements and 2 person got 3 measurements. In this case, there is no reason to assume same correlation structure in each cluster. Can I assume that variances are all the same here? I could have variance in cluster different as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be 10 choose 2 correlation parameters, which are assumed equal across all participants, giving a total of 45. The correlation between measurements at time $t$ and time $t^\prime$ for individual $i$ is $\alpha_{tt^\prime}$, giving correlation matrix

$$
COR(Y,Y) = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & \alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,3} & ... & \alpha_{1,10}\\
\alpha_{1,2} & 1 & \alpha_{2,3} & ... & \alpha_{2,10}\\
\ldots & \ddots & & & \vdots\\
\alpha_{1,10} & \alpha_{2,10} &  & ... & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

That is still a lot of $\alpha$ parameters to estimate, but it's sometimes manageable.

This assumes common observation times in the data. But if some participants missed certain observation times that isn't necessarily a problem. For example, imagine that participant 7 was only observed at times 1 and 10, but missed the middle 8 observations. Then $Cor(Y_{7,1}, Y_{7,10}) = \alpha_{1,10}$ is still a reasonable assumption.

If the assumption of a common correlation structure is unsuitable for your data, then these GEE models should not be used. For example, if you have two groups under study where one group has strong correlations in their responses and the other group does not have correlated responses. I think it might be possible to model the correlation parameters as a function of $X$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What if I have unbalanced case? Say 1 person got 8 measurements and 2 person got 3 measurements. I do not see why those parameters necessarily related to each other. If you are assuming balanced, I may guess individual cluster variance may be different and why correlation inside cluster is necessarily homogeneous? It might be the case, 1 student is from another country, 1 just recovered from hospital and rest are locals.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you are talking about covariance parameters here not correlation. Correlation has diagonal all removed. So there would be 35 correlation parameters.

Comment: @user45765 I added an edit. I don't understand what you mean about correlations inside a cluster being homogeneous. There are also definitely 45 correlation parameters.

Comment: The correlation matrix you took is treated as the same correlation for 10 clusters. If there are more than 2 groups, I could use UGEE approach to estimate parameter of interest. I am only concerned whether I am allowed to use different working correlation for clusters if I have unbalanced setting. I do not see GEE asymptotic unbiasedness proof is related to unbalanced or using different correlation. Probably, calculation of variance estimator requires balanced assumption.